# How to reduce noise on RS485 line?

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit, filter, emc, rs485

[image]

The above picture is the output of a MAX485 IC, which is an RS485 transceiver. When the Cable comes near an AC power line, this kind of noise adds up. Without the presence of the AC main line, its output is clean. I also used a VFD to check the noise level. That adds a more severe level of noise. In this plot, the peak-to-peak amplitude gets almost seven volts. And with VFD, it gets near nine. As RS485 is a differential pair, the data passed properly, but what worries me is the noise amplitude. It seems like the peak-to-peak voltage may destroy my IC. I don't know if it's good to use TVS on that line. There is 125 ohms termination resistor in the bus. Can anyone help me to understand how to suppress it? The oscilloscope probe was connected between terminals A-B and each square is 1.2 volts.

[image: A and B line wave with respect to ground]

[image: Same line but with a VFD running at 1.5 meter distance]

Comment: RS-485 uses a differential signal.  The noise from mains AC should cancel when the receiving side converts from differential to single-ended.  Probe the output of the RS-485 transceiver on the receiving side.  If there's no noise there, then the differential signaling is doing its job, and you're fine.

Comment: What's on the oscilloscope screenshot doesn't look like interference from mains AC (50 Hz or 60 Hz).  The mains AC period is 20 ms or 17ms.  But the noise on the oscilloscope screenshot has a much higher frequency.

Comment: Use the scope as a probe-loop; do you see the same noise?

Comment: It looks like the probed wire has noise spike that exceeds ratings for both the RS-485 standard and the MAX485 chip. You do have common ground between RS-485 devices? RS-485 is not a two wire bus, the devices must share a common ground referece via some route, such as third wire between floating devices, or via mains earth, or chassis, etc. Also it is wrong to put a single scope probe (tip and ground clip) to RS-485 A and B wires, so you might just be measuring wrong.

Comment: Could you get a scope trace with A on channel 1 and B on channel 2 and als othe difference mode?

Comment: What is the device connected to? (Power source, other connections, etc.) Use a fully differential measurement (two probes, each grounded to circuit ground; use math mode to subtract the traces). The waveform shown suggests two types of noise: 1. poor signal quality (undershoot on falling edges), likely due to poor probing method; 2. ambient noise (radio frequency), causing the thickened appearance of the trace, likely due to connected or nearby SMPS or radiotransmitters.

Comment: @Justme I connected to energy meter and a RS485 to USB converter. None of them has ground pin.

Comment: @TimWilliams I can check the voltage with respect to ground tomorrow morning.  I'll edit and update in 12 hours.

Comment: @SadatRafi The meter likely has a manual how to connect it. If the meter RS485 IO is referenced to mains earth, and if your PC is referenced to mains earth, then you already have same ground between them.

Comment: Ok, I'll check with the earth connection. The laptop was battery powered. So there was no common earth Between them.

Comment: So where did you ground the scope probe in relation to where you are measuring?

Comment: Did you use a cable with 125 Ohm impedance? A twisted pair cable? Interference from a parallel AC main line would much less to a twisted cable than to a straight cable without twists.

Comment: @Uwe yes, It's twisted pair and 125 ohms.